# Validation rule: restrict two fields not blank

Tags: validation-rule

I have a validation rule and I would like to restrict the two fields(both are blank). How can i achieve this?

```
AND(
  NOT( $Setup.User_Configuration__c.Account_Validation_Rules__c ),
  NOT(OR(
    $Profile.Name = 'Integration', 
    $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
  )),
  OR(
    ISCHANGED( Name ),
    ISCHANGED( Phone ),
    ISCHANGED( RecordTypeId ),
    ISCHANGED(Client__c), 
    ISCHANGED(Local__c)  
  )
)
```

Comment: which field you want to restrict from keeping it blank??

Answer (score 0):

You can add in more values in your OR function:

```
AND(
  NOT( $Setup.User_Configuration__c.Account_Validation_Rules__c ),
  NOT(OR(
    $Profile.Name = 'Integration', 
    $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
  )),
  OR(
    ISCHANGED( Name ),
    ISCHANGED( Phone ),
    ISCHANGED( RecordTypeId ),
    ISCHANGED(Client__c), 
    ISCHANGED(Local__c),
    ISBLANK(FieldA__c),
    ISBLANK(FieldB__c)
  )
)
```

However, in complicated objects, I'd recommend avoiding doing this, because you can't attach the error to the correct field. Use multiple validation rules.